# How to use viewModel and compose navigation correctly together?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

In the case of using Di, the way it is written on the official Android website is as follows

```
// import androidx.hilt.navigation.compose.hiltViewModel

@Composable
fun MyApp() {
    NavHost(navController, startDestination = startRoute) {
        composable("example") { backStackEntry ->
            // Creates a ViewModel from the current BackStackEntry
            // Available in the androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose artifact
            val exampleViewModel = hiltViewModel<ExampleViewModel>()
            ExampleScreen(exampleViewModel)
        }
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Then if there are a lot of other `@Composable` functions in the ExampleScreen, like this

```
ExampleScreen() {
  A()
  B()
}
A() {
  TopBar()
  BottomBar()
  ....
}
B() ...
```

If both A() and its sub-functions need to use things in vm, don't you have to pass the vm parameters one by one? Because if vm is created in these functions, it is not a singleton(Because navigation compose affects the viewModel, each time you switch the page, these viewModels will be recreated as a new one). When I was puzzled, I saw this design idea on the official website again:

[Pass explicit parameters](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal#explicit-params)

The general idea is that I should pass the logic code of the child function in the parent function, e.g. in ExampleScreen write:

```
ExampleScreen() {
  val vm = hilt<VM>()
  A(onClick = vm.onClick, ...)
  B(...)
}
```

So my question is, if I have a lot of nested functions, don't I need to write a logical parameter in each function? So if I want to create a vm directly in each function, but it is not a singleton, what should I do? Im confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've done the right thing by injecting the viewmodel at the top-level. It's now up to you to decide how you want to pass it down. They're just functions in the end.
You can pass the viewmodel down everywhere, pass down only specific members or pass nothing down.

Do what makes sense and iterate if it doesn't work.

Comment: That's one of the things I'm confused about. If navigation compose is used, what's the point of hilt if you can only pass vm or something else through parameters? It's only created at the top level and passed down, so a normal viewModel can do the same

Comment: Your View model itself might (will) need DI to construct itself. Which is what Hilt will do for you. Once you've constructed it, you just pass it in down yourself.

Comment: I think in this case your view model will be a monolithic view model, essentially the presentation layer for all composable screens.  Maybe favour passing a viewmodel delegate/provider that each composable screen can call for better encapsulation - if you want to use MVVM that is - there is no constraint or obligation to do this.